# How to convert a 2D line equation in General Form to a Slope-intercept Form, in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, floating-point, geometry

I have the equation of a 2D line in the General Form `a x + b y + c = 0` and I need to convert it to the proper Slope-intercept Form; with proper I mean I can choose between `y = m x + q` and `x = m y + q`.

My idea is to check if the line appears "more" horizontal or vertical and consequently choose one of the two Slope-intercept Form.

This is a sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

void abc2mq( double a, double b, double c, double& m, double& q, bool& x2y )
{
   if ( fabs(b) >= fabs(a) ) {
      x2y = true;
      m = -a/b;
      q = -c/b;
   } else {
      x2y = false;
      m = -b/a;
      q = -c/a;
   }
}

void test(double a, double b, double c)
{
   double m,q;
   bool x2y;
   abc2mq( a, b, c, m, q, x2y );
   std::cout << a << " x + " << b << " y + " << c << " = 0\t";
   if ( x2y ) {
      std::cout << "y = " << m << " x + " << q << "\n";
   } else {
      std::cout << "x = " << m << " y + " << q << "\n";
   }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   test(0,0,0);
   test(0,0,1);
   test(0,1,0);
   test(0,1,1);
   test(1,0,0);
   test(1,0,1);
   test(1,1,0);
   test(1,1,1);

   return 0;
}
```

And this is the output

```
0 x + 0 y + 0 = 0       y = -1.#IND x + -1.#IND
0 x + 0 y + 1 = 0       y = -1.#IND x + -1.#INF
0 x + 1 y + 0 = 0       y = -0 x + -0
0 x + 1 y + 1 = 0       y = -0 x + -1
1 x + 0 y + 0 = 0       x = -0 y + -0
1 x + 0 y + 1 = 0       x = -0 y + -1
1 x + 1 y + 0 = 0       y = -1 x + -0
1 x + 1 y + 1 = 0       y = -1 x + -1
```

Any different or better idea? In particular, how can I handle the first two "degenerate" lines?

Comment: @AndreasBrinck I need to draw the lines and the legacy code for drawing a line can accept both the Slope-intercept Forms and so I need to choose the proper one. Unfortunately I can't change the legacy code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost done, just handle the degenerate case.
Add the check for a and b to be non-zero.

```
if(fabs(a) > DBL_EPSILON && fabs(b) > DBL_EPSILON)
{
    ... non-degenerate line handling
} else
{
    // both a and b are machine zeros
    degenerate_line = true;
}
```

Then add the parameter 'degenerate_line':

```
void abc2mq( double a, double b, double c, double& m, double& q, bool& x2y, bool& degenerate_line)
{
    if(fabs(a) > DBL_EPSILON && fabs(b) > DBL_EPSILON)
    {
       if ( fabs(b) >= fabs(a) ) {
           x2y = true;
           m = -a/b;
           q = -c/b;
        } else {
           x2y = false;
           m = -b/a;
           q = -c/a;
        }

        degenerate_line = false;
    } else
    {
        degenerate_line = true;
    }
}
```

And then check for the line to be empty set:

```
void test(double a, double b, double c)
{
    double m,q;
    bool x2y, degenerate;
    abc2mq( a, b, c, m, q, x2y, degenerate );
    std::cout << a << " x + " << b << " y + " << c << " = 0\t";
    if(!degenerate)
    {
       if ( x2y ) {
           std::cout << "y = " << m << " x + " << q << std::endl;
       } else {
           std::cout << "x = " << m << " y + " << q << std::endl;
       }
    } else
    {
       if(fabs(c) > DBL_EPSILON)
       {
          std::cout << "empty set" << std::endl
       } else
       {
          std::cout << "entire plane" << std::endl
       }
    }
}
```

If all you need is to draw the line, just use Thorsten's advice - use the rasterization algorithm instead.

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for a good way to draw these lines, I would recommend using [Bresenham's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) instead of sampling the result of the slope-intercept form of your line equation.
Apologies if this is not what you are trying to do.

Comment: +1, thank you for remembering me the Bresenham's line algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

The equations corresponding to the two degenerated cases do not represent lines but the full plane (ℝ<sup>2</sup>) and the empty set (∅) respectively. The right thing to do is probably to discard them or to throw an error.

For the non degenerate cases, you are already handling them properly.